# Beaglebone black Autoload delay

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack, u-boot

I'm looking for a bit of guidance on how to remove the Autoload delay on a Beaglebone black. The BBB is running Debian Jessie kernel 4.1.18-bone30. The idea is that this BBB will be inside of a consumer product, and the extra 3 seconds at boot is unnecessary. Ideally I'd like the boot time to be <10 seconds, currently I'm sitting at 15. This is from pressing the power button to my application up and running.

My host machine is running ubuntu 12.04 32 bit. My embedded application is running on the Qt framework.

I've been following this tutorial 
http://wiki.beyondlogic.org/index.php/BeagleBoneBlack_Building_Kernel
and this [one](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Linux_Core_U-Boot_User's_Guide),
however the part about how to cut down on the autoload time appears to be missing from the newer kernel. Does anyone know how to change this?

Comment: Hi, how is your research in speeding up beaglebone boot?

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends in part on what version of U-Boot you're using.  For some time, include/configs/am335x_evm.h has inherited CONFIG_BOOTDELAY from (and the include hierarchy varies) from include/config_distro_default.h and that sets it to 2.  You could change that OR edit the default environment that is set in include/configs/am335x_evm.h to have bootdelay=0 to eliminate this delay.

Since you're concerned with boot time you may want to investigate 'Falcon Mode', see http://git.denx.de/?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=doc/README.falcon;h=e9f8a7583c721cd96eb364ff23d591c0284c70b3;hb=HEAD and Beaglebone Black is one of the platforms I've personally done this on so it does work.